# advice on utility of this Moq test case

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I'm in a situation where I'm being told it's my job to write a unit test for the following code.  That's it - test the method using all mocks.  Period.

I'm worried that this is an exercise in writing inverse logic. Furthermore, if there is a subtle bug in this code, I'm going to write a test for that bug, am I not?

```
public EntityLogin GetAccount(string email)
{
    EntityLogin account = null;
    try
    {
        var accounts = _appointmentRepository.GetEntityLogin(_clientContext.selectedSiteId, email);
        if (accounts != null && accounts.Any())
        {
            account = accounts.OrderByDescending(x => x.dtInsertDate).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.ErrorFormat("Error in method '{0}': {1}", MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, ex.GetFullMessage());
        throw;
    }
    return account;
}
```

Here is the test I've come up with.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void GetAccountTest()
    {
        // Arrange
        const string email1 = "a@b.com";
        const string email2 = "c@d.com";
        const string email3 = "e@f.com";
        const string email4 = "g@h.com";

        var expected1 = new EntityLogin {iEntityLoginId = 1234, dtInsertDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-10)};
        var expected2 = new EntityLogin {iEntityLoginId = 5678, dtInsertDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-5)};

        _mockAppointmentRepository
            .Setup(c => c.GetEntityLogin(_siteId, email1))
            .Returns(new[] {expected1})
            .Verifiable();

        _mockAppointmentRepository
            .Setup(c => c.GetEntityLogin(_siteId, email2))
            .Returns((EntityLogin[])null)
            .Verifiable();

        _mockAppointmentRepository
            .Setup(c => c.GetEntityLogin(_siteId, email3))
            .Returns(new EntityLogin[] {})
            .Verifiable();

        _mockAppointmentRepository
            .Setup(c => c.GetEntityLogin(_siteId, email4))
            .Returns(new[] {expected1, expected2})
            .Verifiable();

        var target = GetAppointmentService();

        // Act
        var actual1 = target.GetAccount(email1);
        var actual2 = target.GetAccount(email2);
        var actual3 = target.GetAccount(email3);
        var actual4 = target.GetAccount(email4);

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(expected1, actual1); // returns single result
        Assert.IsNull(actual2); // returns null on null result
        Assert.IsNull(actual3); // returns null on empty collection result
        Assert.AreEqual(actual4, expected2); // sorts desc by insert date on multiple results
        _mockAppointmentRepository.Verify();
    }
```

My question is, **have I done my job properly here?**

Comment: This should probably be asked on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: nobody ever responds over there - i'm hoping to get some advice from some seasoned unit testers out there so my highest chance of that was to post here - if it gets moved or closed I didn't really lose anything

Comment: @AaronAnodide Mock testing is pretty useless in for this kind of code. Your Mocks will simply just return what you expect to assert, the IQueryable logic isn't exercised. Use Fake testing instead, throw out all references to `Moq` here. Personally I like to use EF with SQL CE or SQL LocalDB for my Fake Testing of the EF layer. Also, there are lots of issues with your code here...not least of which is that you have two database calls, `accounts` is never null.

Comment: @Aron Can you elaborate what you mean by fake testing EF with Sql CE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of looking at this situation like you're just writing tests for pre-existing code, consider that you've been tasked with identifying the responsibilities of the SUT. If you write your tests from this angle, you should be able to avoid the situation in which you accidentally codify subtle bugs.

For example, here are what appear to be the SUT's responsibilities:

1. If there are **no accounts** associated with the supplied email address, `GetAccount` returns `null`
2. If there is **one account** associated with the supplied email address, `GetAccount` returns that account
3. If there is **more than one** account associated with the supplied email address, `GetAccount` should return the most recently created account

Each of these scenarios can have its own unit test to verify the expected results. In fact, the test that you provided in your question can essentially be split up into these individual scenarios.

On a side note: you don't really need to `Verify` the behavior of your mock objects - this verification is already implicitly happening by checking their return values. (e.g., How else would `expected1` be returned by the SUT, if the mock repository didn't match the expected arguments?)

Answer (score 1):

Why are you testing several cases in one unit test? Split it to four unit tests like that:

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetAccount_WhenEmailIsNull_ReturnsNull()
{ .. test that is responsible for testing is email null } 

[TestMethod]
public void GetAccount_WhenEmailIsValid_ReturnsAccountsSortedByInsertDate() { .. }
// I'm not sure is "SortedByInsertDate" test should be splitted to another test though
```

etc. When you stay with good naming (Method_WhatIsProvided_WhatShouldBeDoneInSuchCase) - or smth. like that value of your tests will increase. Unit test should test just one thing - when you break your code - you should know what you've broken. Besides unit tests I'm not sure is controlling flow by "null" good idea (and checking for null for something that should return collection is never good idea - you should expect empty collection).

Comment: Although everything you're saying is 100% correct, it is *not* answering the question.

Answer (score 1):

The meat of your code is in your `_appointmentRepository`. Specifically in the `IQueryable<Account>` that is returned by `GetEntityLogin` (I assume you return an IQueryable, because you should be using your database to do your filtering, not your application).

If however you aren't using an `IQueryable` you would have a tightly coupled design between your `SUT` and your `repo`, their behaviors are tied together, with no obvious contract between them. That is to say they must be used together and they must change together, so in effect they are one single class (or a single unit of changable code).

In automated testing there are a few test prototypes for you to use.

- Production code
- Fake
- Stub
- Mock

I will ignore the production code, since its obvious what that is and concentrate on the others.

A Fake is an implementation of the contract that works 100%, but is unsuitable for production for some reason. In this case I suggest faking out your database with SQL CE or LocalDB because it allows you to reuse the maximal amount of your production code. The reason that you can't use the production database for unit testing is because it is shared by production (and thus would affect production). It also can't easily be reset (thus each test isn't in isolation). LocalDB/SQL CE is unsuitable for production because it can't be accessed from multiple locations/application servers. This is exactly the reason why it will isolate your tests from other developers. They also work off of local files, which makes it easily for you to isolate test cases.

A Stub is a class that doesn't implement the contract. They are useful for unit testing as a sort of MacGuffin. The only value of it, is that it exists and its shiny.

A Mock is a class that implements a script instead of a contract. You tell it how to respond to each action and it does so. In my opinion mock testing has the least value out of all forms of testing. You are testing for behavior and not functionality, thus it is brittle. But if you take a look at your SUT here, there is very little behavior in it. You know it should call a single method in `_appointmentRepository`, which seems to be where the meat of this method's logic lives.

So finally I would advise you create a code first `DbContext`. Create a constructor which takes a connection string and a `IDbInitializer`. Then at the start of each test, pass in a new random file location for code first to instanciate a new database file. Use the IDbInitializer to seed the data. Then on clean up, delete the random file.